# DEBUG program not working

Tags: debugging, x86-16, 8085

the question is to print the answer for b+c-d
but i m not getting the anwser...help!!! instead of getting 12 i m getting 49

[here b=10 c=7 d= 5]

```
C:\>debug

    -e 2000
    0AFC:2000  0D.10   0A.7    36.5
    -a 1000
    0AFC:1000 mov al, [2000]
    0AFC:1003 add al, [2001]
    0AFC:1007 sub al, [2002]
    0AFC:100B mov [2003], al
    0AFC:100E hlt
    0AFC:100F
    -g 1000 100F

    Program terminated normally
    -d 2000 2003
    0AFC:2000  10 07 05 49                                       ...I
    -g= 1000 100F
```

Comment: Which segment is DS pointing at?

Comment: replace [2000] with cs:[2000] and make sure every variable fills only one byte.